# Take igraph output and match in new dataset by vertice and dataset name

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I have, what is to me, a rather complicated set of code to construct and I'd really appreciate some help figuring out the various pieces. Essentially, I have 200 different dataframes that will get turned into igraph objects and used for network analysis. The vertices in these networks are people and a person can appear in more than one network. So, I have about 500 **pairs** of networks and people. I've created some sample data of three networks and 6 different people below.

```
mat1<-matrix(data=c(0,4,3,2,0, 1, 3, 4 ,0),nrow=3, ncol=3)
colnames(mat1)<-c("Haley.A", "Carl.F", "Chris.P")
mat1_graph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat1,
                                    weighted=TRUE, mode="directed", diag=FALSE)

mat2<-matrix(data=c(0,3,2,0),nrow=2, ncol=2)
colnames(mat2)<-c("Tom.D", "Chris.P")
mat2_graph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat2,
                                        weighted=TRUE, mode="directed", diag=FALSE)

mat3<-matrix(data=c(0,3,2,1,3,0,5,2,4,4,0,2,1,1,4,0),nrow=4, ncol=4)
colnames(mat3)<-c("Tom.D", "Carl.F", "Charles.L", "Peter.Q")
mat3_graph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat3,
                                        weighted=TRUE, mode="directed", diag=FALSE)
```

I have a data frame that I've created with every pairing of network name and person.
*Note that in my actual data, the network names do NOT follow a naming pattern - they are very different names (unlike the example data of mat1, mat2, etc.)

So, in the case of the example data, the dataframe I've generated would look like:

```
all_pairs<-matrix(data=c("mat1", "Haley.A", "mat1","Carl.F", "mat1","Chris.P", "mat2", "Tom.D", "mat2","Chris.P", "mat3", "Tom.D", "mat3","Carl.F", "mat3","Charles.L", "mat3","Peter.Q"),nrow=9, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(all_pairs)<-c("network_name", "person_name")
all_pairs<-as.data.frame(all_pairs)

print(all_pairs)
  network_name person_name
1         mat1     Haley.A
2         mat1      Carl.F
3         mat1     Chris.P
4         mat2       Tom.D
5         mat2     Chris.P
6         mat3       Tom.D
7         mat3      Carl.F
8         mat3   Charles.L
9         mat3     Peter.Q
```

What I would like is to run the *degree* igraph command on each network and then put the output into the appropriate row for the person and network name match-up.

So, theoretically if I ran `igraph::degree(mat1_graph, mode=c("all"))` and receive this output

```
Haley.A  Carl.F Chris.P 
     4       4       4
```

then I could create a column in the *all_pairs* dataframe and enter the information to look like this:

```
   network_name person_name  degree_all
1          mat1     Haley.A    4
2          mat1      Carl.F    4
3          mat1     Chris.P    4
4          mat2       Tom.D    NA
5          mat2     Chris.P    NA
6          mat3       Tom.D    NA
7          mat3      Carl.F    NA
8          mat3   Charles.L    NA
9          mat3     Peter.Q    NA
```

This would continue for each dataframe and network name/person pair. I'm struggling with how to set up code that would store these values from the igraph package into a dataframe based on the vertice name and dataframe name. I'll then need to do this for every dataset, which I was thinking of using *lapply* for, but am open to better ideas about as well.

Would greatly appreciate any advice and ideas about this puzzle! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use merge to combine two dataframes horizontally.

```
library(igraph)

## creating dataframes, indexed by person, person
mat1<-matrix(data=c(0,4,3,2,0, 1, 3, 4 ,0),nrow=3, ncol=3)
colnames(mat1)<-c("Haley.A", "Carl.F", "Chris.P")
mat2<-matrix(data=c(0,3,2,0),nrow=2, ncol=2)
colnames(mat2)<-c("Tom.D", "Chris.P")
mat3<-matrix(data=c(0,3,2,1,3,0,5,2,4,4,0,2,1,1,4,0),nrow=4, ncol=4)
colnames(mat3)<-c("Tom.D", "Carl.F", "Charles.L", "Peter.Q")

## save in list
mats <- list(mat1=mat1, mat2=mat2, mat3=mat3)

## creating all pairs indexed by network, person
all_pairs<-matrix(data=c("mat1", "Haley.A", "mat1","Carl.F", "mat1","Chris.P",
                         "mat2", "Tom.D", "mat2","Chris.P",
                         "mat3", "Tom.D", "mat3","Carl.F", "mat3","Charles.L", "mat3","Peter.Q"), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(all_pairs)<-c("network_name", "person_name")

## convert dataframes to graphs
## calculate degrees and collect   
all_dfs <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=3))
processed <- c(1,3)
for (i in processed) {
  df      <- mats[i]
  ggg     <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(df[[1]], weighted=TRUE, mode="directed", diag=FALSE)
  dd1     <- degree(ggg, mode=c("all"))
  dd2     <- data.frame(cbind(names(df), names(dd1), dd1), row.names=NULL)

  # all_dfs <- rbind(all_dfs, dd2)                      ## slow
  all_dfs[nrow(all_dfs) + seq(nrow(dd2)), ] <- dd2      ## faster
}
colnames(all_dfs) <- c(colnames(all_pairs), "degree")
 
## comparing all_pairs with all processed dataframes
comp <- merge(x = all_pairs, y = all_dfs, by= c("network_name", "person_name"), all = TRUE)
comp
```

Gives.

```
 network_name person_name degree
1         mat1      Carl.F      4
2         mat1     Chris.P      4
3         mat1     Haley.A      4
4         mat2     Chris.P   <NA>
5         mat2       Tom.D   <NA>
6         mat3      Carl.F      6
7         mat3   Charles.L      6
8         mat3     Peter.Q      6
9         mat3       Tom.D      6
```